# Why getting NullPointerException error in AnyLogic while using wait block?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a agent "client" which contain 3 variables (all are initially false)

1. var_puttingFreeService
2. var_massageService
3. var_simulatorService

Now in the Main, I create an "event" which repeat in every 1 minute.
This event check if `wait.size > 1` and any service is empty, then free the first agent from "wait" if all the above mentioned variable values are false for this agent.

[image]
[image]

But i am getting "NullPointerException" error even though the wait block is not empty.
[image]

Kindly let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: the null value is not related to the wait, even though you code is still wrong,

Comment: Can you explain it a little more. I will highly appreciate that.

Comment: I solved the NullPointerException. It was causing because of population of the agent. But the code is not working as expected can you explain the issue with it in detail.
Thank you.

Comment: The code of event works jut fine unless the wait.size = 0. so I suspend the event when size of wait become 0 and when a new agent enters in the wait I restart the event. So now it is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to understand is that
false && false || true || false

is true

you need to use parenthesis appropriately and the && takes precence over the ||

so you should do

```
if (wait.size()>1 && (delay1.size()==0 || delay2.size()==0))
```

you see the difference?

Comment: yes i did. Its clear now.